# String query Search and filter between Dates

Tags: sql, date, search, filter, between

```
String query = "SELECT * 
                FROM salesTable 
                where timeStamp BETWEEN '"+startdate+"' 
                AND '"+enddate+"' ( sellid LIKE '%"+search_str+"%'  
                OR tastemodel LIKE '%"+search_str+"%'  
                OR bezeichnung LIKE '%"+search_str+"%' 
                OR sellid LIKE '%"+lastName+" "+firstName +"%'      ) 
                ORDER BY timeStamp DESC";
```

How can I combine a normal string search with between two dates?

Comment: ...by using `AND` i.e. `'"+enddate+"' AND ( sellid LI`

Comment: cool, i added it as an answer so you can mark it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By properly combining the terms using `AND`.

```
...'" + enddate + "' AND (sellid LI...
//                   ^^^
```